# Empty tree view

Tags: odoo, odoo-10

I can't get the tree view to display any data at all even I can create entries with no problem and they appear in the database

Here is the view xml:

```html
        <record id="view_invoice_lab_tree" model="ir.ui.view">
            <field name="name">lab.invoice.tree</field>
            <field name="model">lab.invoice</field>
            <field name="arch" type="xml">
                <tree string="Labs Invoices">
                   
                    <field name="name" string="invoice Number"/>
                    <field name="create_date"/>
                    <field name="patient_id"/>
                    <field name="amount_total"/>
                </tree>
            </field>
        </record>
```

Model Structure:

```html
class LabOrderLine(models.Model):
    _name = 'lab.order.line'
    _description = 'labs Order Line'
    name = fields.Text(string='Description', required=True)
    order_id = fields.Many2one('lab.invoice', string='Invoice Reference', required=True, ondelete='cascade', index=True, copy=False)


    nameLab = fields.Many2one(
        string='Lab',
        comodel_name='medical.lab.patient',
        required=True,
        ondelete='cascade',
    )

    patient_id= fields.Many2one(
        'medical.patient',
        string='patient',
         related='nameLab.patient_id',
         readonly=True,
        required=True,
    )
```

```html
class labinvoice (models.Model):
    _name = "lab.invoice"
    name = fields.Char(string='Invoice Reference',  default=lambda self: _('New'), store=True)
    order_line = fields.One2many('lab.order.line', 'order_id', string='Order Lines', copy=True,  )  
    nameLab = fields.Many2one('medical.lab.patient',related='order_line.nameLab',string='name Lab', store=True)
    patient_id = fields.Many2one('medical.patient',related='order_line.patient',string='name Patient', store=True, readonly=True )
```

I think the problem is with the One2many field

Comment: What `model` are you talking about? The tree view of `lab.invoice` or `lab.order.line`

Comment: I'm talking about lab.invoice

Comment: Okay. Then where is `amount_total` defined?

Comment: on lab.invoice I just didn't list all the fields here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of the things that I had is maybe you have used a domain in the window action and afterwards, you removed the domain from the action.

Removing the domain line from your code will not remove the domain from the action in the database.

So if you defined a domain to remove you should use this

```
   <field name="domain">[]</field>
```

Same thing for context or any other field.

Hope this helps you

Comment: You can view the Window Action in the Odoo back end to see if there is anything extra that is unintended. You need to be in Developer Mode, then go to Settings > Technical > Window Actions.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, check if you have or had a field including the field name "active". By default it doesn't show fields not active.